# How to Add a Foreign key in my SQL

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

I am using spring mvc and hibernate. I created a lot of one to many mappings in this project, but now when I try to add a foreign key, I get the error bellow.

MY SQL

```
ALTER TABLE `project_dashboard_db`.`members` ADD COLUMN `releaseID` INT(10) UNSIGNED AFTER `phoneNum`,
 ADD CONSTRAINT `releaseID` FOREIGN KEY `releaseID` (`releaseID`)
    REFERENCES `releases` (`releaseID`)
    ON DELETE RESTRICT
    ON UPDATE RESTRICT;
```

**Error:**

```
Error while executing query.

ALTER TABLE `project_dashboard_db`.`members` ADD COLUMN `releaseID` INT(10) UNSIGNED AFTER `phoneNum`,
 ADD CONSTRAINT `releaseID` FOREIGN KEY `releaseID` (`releaseID`)
    REFERENCES `releases` (`releaseID`)
    ON DELETE RESTRICT
    ON UPDATE RESTRICT;


MySQL Error Number 1005
Can't create table 'project_dashboard_db.#sql-54c_d' (errno: 121)
```

Comment: Which DB engine you are using InnoDB or MyISAM?

Comment: i am using MY SQL..DB engiing ..i am not clear..i am new..Thanks

Comment: How you are accessing mysql? Means which IDE or terminal

Comment: using my sql Query Browser

Comment: Download `MySQL Workbench` http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/tools/workbench/ . It provide GUI based table properties and other stuff as well. Much better than Query browser. Setting foreign keys would be easy in it.

Answer (score 0):

try this

use project_dashboard_db;

ALTER TABLE `members` ADD COLUMN `releaseID` INT(10) UNSIGNED AFTER `phoneNum`;

ALTER TABLE `members`  ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_releaseID` FOREIGN KEY(`releaseID`)
    REFERENCES `releases`(`releaseID`)
    ON DELETE RESTRICT
    ON UPDATE RESTRICT;

it would be better if you would type the command " show create table releases " and display the output here......